# A Message to the SE Admins

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crossword-clues, metapuzzles

We're graduating! I feel the only appropriate way to respond is a Stack Exchange themed puzzle:

- Albertan politician who succeeded Lucien Maynard (6, 7 or 6, 8)
- Approved for passport authorization (6)
- Famous stage direction from *The Winter's Tale* (4, 7, 2, 1, 4)
- Method of hiding messages undetected inside images, audio, or text (13)
- Pigment made from antimony (6, 6)
- Rapper or theater worker (5)
- Revealed or exposed - what the Scooby-Doo gang did to the villain of the week (both literally and figuratively!) (8)
- Voice of Carl from *Up* (2, 5)

What's my message to the SE admins? You'll know it when you find it.

Comment: It seems the SE admins liked your message so much that they gave you a diamond as a reward ;-)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The message for the SE Admins is:

> Thank You!

This can be found by looking at something hidden in the answers to each of the clues:

Albertan politician who succeeded Lucien Maynard (6, 7)

> Arthur S**o**etaert

Approved for passport authorization (6)

> Vis**a**ed

Famous stage direction from The Winter's Tale (4, 7, 2, 1, 4)

> *Exit, purs**u**ed by a bear*

Method of hiding messages undetected inside images, audio, or text (13)

> S**t**eganography

Pigment made from antimony (6, 6)

> Naples **y**ellow

Rapper or theater worker (5)

> Us**h**er

Revealed or exposed - what the Scooby-Doo gang did to the villain of the week (both literally and figuratively!) (8)

> Unmas**k**ed

Voice of Carl from Up (2, 5)

> Ed As**n**er

All of these answers have

> the pattern `S?E` in them with a letter replacing the question mark. If you rearrange them by the position of `S?E` you get...
>
> ```
>  STEGANOGRAPHY
>  USHER
>  VISAED
>  EDASNER
>  UNMASKED
>  NAPLESYELLOW
>  ARTHURSOETART
>  EXITPURSUEDBYABEAR
> ```
>
> Then just read the letters in between and you get "THANK YOU"!

Comment: All correct! Like I said in chat though, the real challenge is combining them together. ;) (Ernest Manning is wrong, actually)

Comment: Hold on, my source spelled his name differently - it should be (6,8) according to the Wikipedia spelling.

Comment: @Deusovi That was one I had to look up - I went with the name that matched the number count (but probably was wrong on province of origin)  - fixed now.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me editing your answer as you'd done most of the hard work.

Comment: @GordonK Not at all, thanks! I was stuck on the passport one, great find!

Comment: Nice job so far! It's not just an anagram - take another look. I'll accept when you find the ordering mechanism.

Comment: Edited that part in, then :)

Comment: Now what would be *really nice* is if this puzzle, serendipitously, ended up in the Hot Questions sidebar

Comment: @question_asker Look! :D